# Solution to multi server environment with a CodeIgniter website

Tags: codeigniter

I have a local, staging and production environment for my CodeIgniter based site. Increasingly I find everytime I deploy a version I have more and more little bits of code to change because of server variations.

What would be a good (and quick) solution I could add that would allow me to set these variables by just using one setting. Where would be the best place to insert this in the index.php, some sort of hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define a "LIVE" constant which is TRUE or FALSE based on the current domain its on (put this in your index.php file)

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'mylivesite.com'))
{
    define('LIVE', TRUE);
}
else
{
    define('LIVE', FALSE);
}
```

and then check to see if you are live or not and assign the variables accordingly

```
if(LIVE)
{
    $active_group = "production";
}
else
{
    $active_group = "test";
}
```

ive been doing this with our 5 environment setup for the past year with no problems

Comment: -1, but I think only because this is an old answer the CI team has provided a new capability.  A quick revision and I would remove my down vote.

Comment: +1 because this applies to CI 1.x, which the asker was clearly using, based on the date. DigitalSea's answer explains this.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Apache, you can set an environmental variable which can be read by PHP in your Virtual Hosts file for the site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/site
    ServerName local.mysite.com
    ErrorLog /path/to/error_log
    CustomLog /path/to/access_log common
    <Directory /path/to/site>
        SetEnv ENVIRONMENT local
        RewriteEngine On
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Options FileInfo
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So with that, you now can check for and set the server environment accordingly in your index.php file:

```
// always default to production for safety
$environment = 'production';

// check for an environment override
if (function_exists('apache_getenv') && apache_getenv("ENVIRONMENT")) {
  $environment = apache_getenv("ENVIRONMENT");
} else if (getenv("ENVIRONMENT")) {
  $environment = getenv("ENVIRONMENT");
}

// set the environment constant
define('ENVIRONMENT', $environment);
```

With this setup, you now have the freedom to deploy your sites and add additional configuration parameters to your `application/config/[file].php` files for each environment.

### Alternative...

Another possibility for handling multi-environment setups is to create a file outside of the document root and is ignored by your version control system (i.e. .gitignore) which contains the value of the server environment. You could then just read that file via `file_get_contents()` or equivalent.

Comment: I was confused at first, but this is a nice alternative to reading $_SERVER variables.

Answer (score 2):

An old question, but Codeigniter Reactor has support for environment variables built in now. You simply open up the index.php file and choose your environment. There is a post about them here: http://ilikekillnerds.com/2011/03/how-to-use-codeigniter-reactor-environment-variables/

Answer (score 1):

The official [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html) doc suggests this for multiple database environment:

Gobal variable in config.php file to set the environment:

$active_group = "test";

Multiple settings in database.php

```
$db['test']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['test']['username'] = "root";
$db['test']['password'] = "";
$db['test']['database'] = "database_name";
...

$db['production']['hostname'] = "example.com";
$db['production']['username'] = "root";
$db['production']['password'] = "";
$db['production']['database'] = "database_name";
...
```

See the doc for further details.

Comment: Yeah I have this but also many other variables in other files API keys etc. What would be the best way to manage these?

Answer (score 1):

Having many little bits of code that change because of server variations is a bad sign that you're modifying code that's not supposed to be modified for the application. The only things that you're supposed to change between servers is your configuration variables located in `config.php`, which should have default values for the developers to change depending on the environment.

Comment: +1 http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html CodeIgniter also provides the facility to have different config files based on the ENVIRONMENT setting from index.php