# Setup Environment Database, sytem folder, application folder, for codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

I checked this answer on [Solution to multi server environment with a CodeIgniter website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239862/solution-to-multi-server-environment-with-a-codeigniter-website) 
Happens that testing it with a simple echo like this

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'mylivesite.com'))
{
    define('LIVE', TRUE);
    echo "LIVE";
}
else
{
    define('LIVE', FALSE);
    echo "NOT LIVE";
}
```

Won't work. Always says its NOT LIVE.
But this way.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'mylivesite.com')
{
    define('LIVE', TRUE);
    echo "LIVE";
}
else
{
    define('LIVE', FALSE);
    echo "NOT LIVE";
}
```

Says its live when on remote server.

What would be the problem?
Would be any problem to do  with ==='mylivesite.com'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'mylivesite.com') === false)
{
    define('LIVE', FALSE);
    echo "NOT LIVE";
}
else
{
    define('LIVE', TRUE);
    echo "LIVE";
}
```

Will make it work as expected.